# Advanced lookups in Pandas Dataframe Part 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I used the following solution from Stef that I had raised previously. Please read problem in the link first: [Advanced lookups in Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69976406/advanced-lookups-in-pandas-dataframe/69977888#69977888)

However, the problem I have now have is when I have additional accounts ending in 8409 that doesn't have a corresponding 8400 account the 8409 returns a NaN value for level2. If a 8409 doesn't have a corresponding account then it just should retain its current value in "level2" column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([['USD',7854568400,489],
                    ['USD',9632588400,126],
                    ['USD',3699633691,189],
                    ['USD',9876543697,987],
                    ['EUR',1111118409,987],
                    ['USD',1111118409,987],
                    ['USD',7854568409,396],
                    ['USD',7854567893,897],      
                    ['USD',9632588409,147]],
columns = ['cur','level1','level2'])
```

Output:

```
cur level1  level2
0   USD 7854568400  489
1   USD 9632588400  126
2   USD 3699633691  189
3   USD 9876543697  987
4   EUR 1111118409  987
5   USD 1111118409  987
6   USD 7854568409  396
7   USD 7854567893  897
8   USD 9632588409  147
```

I applied the following solution:

```
df.level2 = df.merge(df.assign(level1 = df.level1.astype(str).str.replace('8409$', '8400', regex=True).astype('int64')), on='level1', how='right')['level2_x']
```

Current Output:

```
cur level1  level2
0   USD 7854568400  489.0
1   USD 9632588400  126.0
2   USD 3699633691  189.0
3   USD 9876543697  987.0
4   EUR 1111118409  NaN
5   USD 1111118409  NaN
6   USD 7854568409  489.0
7   USD 7854567893  897.0
8   USD 9632588409  126.0
```

Index 4 is the issue, since there was no corresponding 8400 account it returned NaN but the desired output should retain its initial value in column level 2.

Thanks in advance if anyone has a workaround for this?

Comment: what do you expect to do here? The behavior is fully normal, you change a value, merge on the column, there is a NaN on the non matching value…

Comment: The non matching case for account 1111118409 needs to retain its original value in column level2 and not NaN. The program needs to search to see if account 8409 has a corresponding 8400 account and if so replace the level2 value from the 8400 account to the 8409 account which is working as expected. But when there is no match found, then the 8409 account just retains its original value otherwise it keeps returning NaN for these cases.

Comment: the original solution only factored in when there was always a corresponding match and that is the problem.

Comment: I see, I provided a functional solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that should work as you expect:

```
maps = df.set_index('level1')['level2']
s = df['level1'].astype(str).str.replace('8409$', '8400', regex=True).astype('int64')
df['new_level2'] = s.map(maps).combine_first(df['level2']).convert_dtypes()
```

output:

```
       level1  level2  new_level2
0  7854568400     489         489
1  9632588400     126         126
2  3699633691     189         189
3  9876543697     987         987
4  1111118409     987         987
5  7854568409     396         489
6  7854567893     897         897
7  9632588409     147         126
```

Comment: that has worked a treat. I did however leave off one other variable. I've updated the original post above. This is the currency column, these matching would only be applicable to USD accounts and its doesn't apply to any other currency. All other currencies just retain what it has in level2. My apologies, I can add this to a new topic since you did solve what I had initially post? Let me know.

Comment: @AlanPaul then you should go with a left join/merge on the common columns, then apply combine_first to replace the NaN with the original values

Comment: okay let me try that

Comment: look like the problem I have now there can be account numbers containing the same digits but just differs by currency  - the following error appears as a result `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`